# Is it possible to template metaprogram index-dependent functions in for loops in C++?

Tags: c++, indexing, metaprogramming

Basically what I want to do is assign a function inside a for loop nest ONCE with a template. My current approach calls onto a vector of functions (see below), but this is expensive because the function is called on every loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int func0(int k, int j, int i) {int that{(j + 2) + ( i) + k};     return that; }
int func1(int k, int j, int i) {int that{(i + 2) + (k) + j};     return that; }
int func2(int k, int j, int i) {int that{(k + 2) + ( k) + i};     return that; }
int func3(int k, int j, int i) {int that{(j + j) + (j) + i};     return that; }

void myfunction(int idx)
{
    int (*funcs[])(int k, int j, int i) =
        {func0, func1, func2, func3};

    int N = 10;

    int value;

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                value = funcs[idx](k, j, i); // this makes a call to func of index idx ON EVERY LOOP
                printf("%d ", value);
                std::cout << value;
            }
}

int main()
{
    int k=0; int k2 =0;
    while (k < 100){
        myfunction(k2);
        k++; k2++;
        k2%=4;
    }
}
```

I would like funcs to be a template rather than a vector. My other option is to define a myfunction() for every func, but this makes for too much code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are concerned with `funcs[idx]` being evaluated every time in the inner loop, just hoist it out of the loop: `auto func = funcs[idx]` and use `func` in place of `funcs[idx]`

Comment: If the goal is to have `func0` et al inlined, you'd have to unroll the loop. [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/asWvWb81M)

Comment: Thank you Igor, that was really helpful. Best.